# Change the row names in R

Tags: r, dataframe

i have two dataframes with similar rownames:

```
> rownames(abundance)[1:10]
 [1] "X001.V2.fastq_mapped_to_agora.txt.uniq" 
 [2] "X001.V8.fastq_mapped_to_agora.txt.uniq" 
 [3] "X003.V17.fastq_mapped_to_agora.txt.uniq"
 [4] "X003.V2.fastq_mapped_to_agora.txt.uniq" 
 [5] "X003.V8.fastq_mapped_to_agora.txt.uniq" 
 [6] "X004.V2.fastq_mapped_to_agora.txt.uniq" 
 [7] "X004.V8.fastq_mapped_to_agora.txt.uniq" 
 [8] "X005.V2.fastq_mapped_to_agora.txt.uniq" 
 [9] "X005.V8.fastq_mapped_to_agora.txt.uniq" 
[10] "X006.V2.fastq_mapped_to_agora.txt.uniq" 
> rownames(fluxes)[1:10]
 [1] "001.V8"  "003.V17" "003.V2"  "003.V8"  "004.V2"  "004.V8"  "005.V2" 
 [8] "005.V8"  "006.V2"  "006.V8"
```

But the row names of the dataframe **abundance** is larger. How can i make the names of each rows like the rownames of **fluxes**. It can be like from "X" to second ".".

Answer (score 2):

We may use `trimws`

```
rownames(abundance) <- trimws(rownames(abundance), whitespace = "\\..*")
```

Or could be

```
rownames(abundance) <- sub("^([^.]+\\.[^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", rownames(abundance))
```

-testing

```
> trimws("X001.V2.fastq_mapped_to_agora.txt.uniq",  whitespace = "\\..*")
[1] "X001"
> sub("^([^.]+\\.[^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", "X001.V2.fastq_mapped_to_agora.txt.uniq")
[1] "X001.V2"
```

Comment: opps sorry it should be to the second dot.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `sub`:

```r
rownames(abundance) <- sub("X(.*)\\.fastq_mapped_to_agora\\.txt\\.uniq", "\\1", rownames(abundance))
```

Output:

```r
[1] "001.V2"  "001.V8"  "003.V17" "003.V2"  "003.V8"  "004.V2"  "004.V8"  "005.V2"  "005.V8"  "006.V2"
```

Comment: it didnt work. my bad. there are other values begin with like X100, X21.

Comment: like:

X100_HC_Fe
X10A_DNA_Bio
X10A_DNA_Fe
X10A_cDNA_Fe
X10E_DNA_Bio
X10E_DNA_Fe
X10E_cDNA_Fe
X10F_DNA_Bio
X10F_DNA_Fe
X10F_cDNA_Fe
X10G_DNA_Bio

Comment: What should be extracted then? @akrun's answer is probably the best then.